# How to implement swipeable list item?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'd like to have similar result than the iOS native Mail app, 
where you can swipe left a message to see additional actions 
[Graphical example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwQmK.gif).
The questions is, should I implement a component from the scratch or is something out there that I can reuse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [dancormier/react-native-swipeout](https://github.com/dancormier/react-native-swipeout) but there are others, such as [jlevine22/react-native-swipeable-element](https://github.com/jlevine22/react-native-swipeable-element) for instance.